# Sublime Text 3 says UNREGISTERED in menu/title bar

Tags: sublime-text, license

I downloaded/installed Sublime Text 3 via the .deb package and inserted my license. The window popped up saying thank you for registering.

However, it still says unregistered in the menu/title bar. How can I remove it? Minor annoyance after spending the money to get a license.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. The .desktop file shows "Sublime Text", but the Unity launcher and Switcher both show the (UNREGISTERED) message.

Comment: Same here. I am on Ubuntu 15.10 and Sublime Text 3 (3103)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I just had this issue as well and it turned out it was just the unity link  file that needed to be updated. The link was created before I registered sublime so the link name gets created with the `UNREGISTERED` string.

I was able to fix this by modifying the link file.

```
vim ~/.local/share/applications/sublime_text.desktop
```

You can then change the `Name=` entry

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Sublime Text -- UNREGISTERED
Icon=sublime_text.png
Exec=/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text
StartupNotify=false
StartupWMClass=Sublime_text
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
X-UnityGenerated=true
```

Comment: Is there a way to have changes update without having to log out and back in?

Comment: @smhg, quit sublime text and unlock it from the launcher. Start sublime text again, and relock it to launcher.